# Django - render relevant value from queryset in template

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I am rendering data from my views into my template, as follows:

```
<tbody>
    {% for item in lyrics %}
    <tr class='lyrics-table'>
      <td>{{item}}</td>
      <td>
      {% if item in user_flash %}
         <p>{{flash_answer}}</p>
       {% else %}
        <p>xxx</p>
      {% endif %}
     </td>
```

My views are as follows:

```
class SongVocab(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model= models.Song
    template_name = 'videos/song_vocab.html'
    context_object_name = 'song'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        from pymystem3 import Mystem
        m = Mystem()
        user_flash = Flashcard.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).values_list('question', flat=True)
        lyrics_list = models.Song.objects.get().lyrics_as_list()
        user_flash_ = [item.replace('\n', ' ') for item in m.lemmatize(" ".join(user_flash))]
        user_flash_clean = [w for w in user_flash_ if w.strip()]  ##removes empty strings
        lyrics_list_ = [item.replace('\n', ' ') for item in m.lemmatize(" ".join(lyrics_list))]
        lyrics_list_clean = [w for w in lyrics_list_ if len(w.strip())]
        user_word = list(set(user_flash_clean) & set(lyrics_list_clean))

        import icu # PyICU
        def sorted_strings(strings, locale=None):
            if locale is None:
                return sorted(strings)
            collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale(locale))
            return sorted(strings, key=collator.getSortKey)
        context['percent_known'] = ((len(user_word))/(len(set(lyrics_list_clean))))*100
        context['lyrics'] = sorted_strings(set(lyrics_list_clean),"ru_RU.UTF8")
        context['user_flash'] = user_flash_clean

        context['flash_answer'] = []
        for word in user_word:
        flash = Flashcard.objects.get(owner=self.request.user, question=word)
        context['flash_answer'].append(flash.answer)

    return context
```

My question is: how can I render the relevant `flash_answer` for every `user_word` in my template? At the moment, I get the entire queryset, which makes sense, because that is what `flash_anwswer` is. But the two are linked, so there must be a way, but I have no idea how to do it. Do I need to change my view, or is there a way I can render it differently in the template?

**Update** - I'm now thinking that I need to create a dictionary in my views, but I'm not sure how to do it. So I have:

`user_word` - gives a list containing words where the user's flashcard overlaps with a word in lyrics.

So how can I now get a dictionary that shows for example:

`{'question': relevant word from lyrics, 'answer': flash_answer}`

But how can I match the two and get "relevant word from lyrics"? Almost like doing a vlookup in excel... I'm completely lost!

**Update**: I tried this, which sort of works, except I get only one value instead of all of them...

```
    z = []
    m = {'question': [], 'answer': []}
    for word in user_word:
        x = lyrics_list_clean.index(word)
        y = user_word.index(word)
        flash = Flashcard.objects.get(owner=self.request.user, question=word)
        z.append(flash.answer)
        m['question'].append(lyrics_list_clean[x])
        m['answer'].append(z[y])
        context['test'] = m
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
flash_answers = {}
for flash_obj in Flashcard.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user, question__in=user_word):
    flash_answers.setdefault(flash_obj.question, [])
    flash_answers.append(flash_obj.answer)
  
context['lyrics'] = [{
            'text': lyrics_str,
            'need_flash': lyrics_str in flash,
            'flash_answer': flash_answers.get(lyrics_str, '')
        } for lyrics_str in  sorted_strings(set(lyrics_list_clean),"ru_RU.UTF8")]
```

and then in html file you can do

```
{% for item in lyrics %}
    <tr class='lyrics-table'>
      <td>{{item.text}}</td>
      <td>
      {% if item.need_flash %}
         <p>{% for answer in item.flash_answer%}answer {%endfor%}</p>
       {% else %}
        <p>xxx</p>
      {% endif %}
     </td>
```

Comment: I'm still getting the entire queryset

Comment: I get the following error on the `flash_obj.question` line: `get() returned more than one Flashcard -- it returned 10!`

Comment: if you can have many items per one word we need to rebuild our flash_answers. do it in 3 minutes

Comment: Strange, I would have thought there should only be one

Comment: i modified answer, check it now

Comment: Still the same error. I tried something different (see last update in my question). It sort of works, except I get only one value, instead of many. Any ideas?

Comment: in my answer, spaces goes wrong when i copy it here. will correct now. we should prepare context out of the first loop. In your modification  you create dictionary wrong, you have separate lists -  questions, answers, so there is now much sense in your dictionary

Comment: and one more mistake. i used objects.get(...), instead of objects.filter(...) and that was a mistake. probably if you have only 1 answer for each question first variant should work too)

Comment: `append` is not allowed for a dictionary. If I replace this with `update` I get the error: `dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`. Also, where is `lyrics_str` coming from?

Comment: need to replace `flash_answers.append(flash_obj.answer)` with `flash_answers[flash_obj.question].append(flash_obj.answer)`

Comment: And `lyrics_str` - what is that supposed to be? `lyrics_list_clean`? Also `flash` - should that be `user_flash`? Sorry, but I'm a bit confused...

Comment: sorry, i renamed variable and forgot to do it everywhere. replace text_lyrics with lyrics_str. i modified answer